# Permissions error accessing NServiceBus MSMQ from MVC .Net

Tags: iis-6, msmq, nservicebus

I have written a mvc that uses nservicebus to publish messages. This works fine under Cassini.

When trying to use IIS, I receive an error message when I call Create() to create the Bus.

Access to Message Queuing system is denied.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: Access to Message Queuing system is denied.

I have set the anonymous access user on the IIS virtual directory to be my own domain account, which is a member of the administrators group on the local machine. I have granted this same user full permissions on the queue, as well as NETWORK SERVICE and ASPNET.

Any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to delete the queues.

I tried using the FormatName in the MsmqTransportConfig section of my web.config, as recommended in [Permissions error accessing MSMQ from ASP .Net Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734417/permissions-error-accessing-msmq-from-asp-net-web-service).  That did not work.

Deleting the queues did.