# MSMQ exception occuring during queue creation

Tags: c#, msmq

I'm trying to create message queue:

```
MessageQueue.Create(path, true);
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

> The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to
>   perform the operation.

But queue was created in spite of exception. I tried several times:

1. Remove queue
2. Invoke create method
3. Exception occurs
4. Queue was created.

Could someone tell me the reason of exception? How can I avoid it?

**Edited**:

I tried on different machine. The same behavior.

OS: Windows 7. Console application. Runned by user with admin rights.

Comment: I haven't had this issue myself but Perhaps this could be related

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734417/permissions-error-accessing-msmq-from-asp-net-web-service

Comment: did you look for an error in the event log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how it can be avoided.

Path was equal to `@"**localhost**\Private$\Queue"`.

I changed it to `@"**.**\Private$\Queue"` and the exception disappeared.

But the reason is still unclear.